# Java Swing animation ghost issue

Tags: java, swing, bluej

Just a forewarning: I'm new to java - I normally use UnrealScript and C# but I'm branching out, so there is likely one or two things I've done incorrectly or against the normal java convection (that would be more in align with convictions of those other two languages)

Feel free to point them out, and I'll mold myself to them accordingly

---

I'm making a JRPGish style game in java using BlueJ. I'm not aiming massively high, and am more doing it as a proof-of-concept rather than a full blown game.

So far its going ok. I'm got a sprite animation working using a sprite sheet and the player can walk around with the sprite changing to the correct animation depending on the direction.

However I'm having an issue when the player stops moving - there sometimes is a afterimage of the previous frame - In fairness, this may be happening all the time except you cant see it if the player stops moving on the first and last frame of the walking animations, as those take up the same pixel space and thus are hidden (if that makes sense)

Here is an image of the issue in action:

[image: Player after moving right]

This is after the player has moved, and then stopped, leaving the last frame of the "moveRight" sprite behind.

---

I have created a small version of my project that has just the character animation playing when you press a key, and stopping when you release, in which the issue appears

The [Skeleton class](http://pastebin.com/SymnS3hG)

The [Character class](http://pastebin.com/gYd669d1)

The [GameManager class](http://pastebin.com/PhCFdRMi)

The [KeyManager class](http://pastebin.com/uDdBma4J)

To start the game run the Main method in GameManager

You'll need to save this image with the filename of "James.png" and place it in the same folder of the java project for it to work

[image]

Thanks in advance for any help given.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`paintComponent()` passes `Graphics` to `drawCharactor()`. `drawCharactor()` should not disposes that `Graphics` object unless you made a copy, this `Graphics` is shared.

Also, do not call `repaint()` from `drawCharactor()`. `repaint()` schedules another paint cycle. You already do call `repaint()` from a timer.

Do not use `java.util.Timer` use `javax.swing.Timer` for Swing painting. See [How to Use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

For more information and examples [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)  and [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html).

Consider posting a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Oh woops - that repaint shouldnt be there in drawCharactor. I left it in there when I went to bed last night as I was playing around with it to see if that might fix it (Its mentioned in an article somewhere). Thanks I'll try out your answer now and see if that helps.

Comment: Your comment about the timer is interesting - I learned about doing timer animation in java from this: http://zetcode.com/tutorials/javagamestutorial/animation/

Quoting: "In the first example we will use a Swing timer to create animation. This is the easiest but also the least effective way of animating objects in Java games."

I'll look into it more, as this is programming after all :)

Comment: I have applied your answer to my code to no effect - The issue still remains

Comment: @GarethJones `javax.swing.Timer` performs tasks in the `Event Dispatch Thread`.

Comment: @GarethJones any chance you could post the missing code and images to make your example runnable?

Comment: oh sure. Everything I'm using is free, so I can share away. By missing code I assume you mean the other classes? I'll post them up now along with the updated character class

Comment: @GarethJones consider slimming it down and making a short example that can demonstrate the problem. There is no need for all the extra code and logic.

Comment: I've uploaded said small example, showing off just the charactor sprite issue at hand

Comment: @GarethJones comment out `setBackground( c );` line, see if it helps.

Comment: Yes that does it. That also solves my second issue. However because the background now has alpha, the character doesn't let the background show through. Is there another way I can do that in Java?

Comment: @GarethJones `Color( 0,0,0,0 )` is transparent. `JPanel` is opaque by default. Try `setOpaque(false);`

Comment: Ah ha! perfect! works fine, and solves both issues. Thanks a million! :)

Comment: @GarethJones you're welcome! I'm glad it worked out:) +1 for a nice question.